# How can I download all attachments from a folder in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

How to download all files from a folder in ColdFusion? I have a folder named "abc" and there are 5 different files in it. So I want to download all 5 files when I click on a hyperlink.

Currently, this is the code I am trying. It is downloading a selected file, but how do I download all files in it?

```
<cfheader name="Content-disposition" value='attachment; filename="database_error.png"'>
```

Comment: you can create a zip file containing all your files and download it together.

Answer (score 10):

Check this code

```
<cfset fileName = createUUID() />
<cfif DirectoryExists("D:/tempDir")>
    <cfdirectory action = "list" directory = "D:/tempDir" name = "getAllFiles"  type="file" />
        <cfzip action="zip" file="D:/zipfilefolder/#fileName#.zip" overwrite="yes" >
            <cfloop query="getAllFiles">    
                <cfzipparam  source="D:/tempDir/#getAllFiles.name#">
            </cfloop>
        </cfzip>
</cfif>
<cfheader name = "Content-disposition" value = 'attachment; filename="D:/zipfilefolder/#fileName#.zip"'>
<cfcontent deleteFile="true" file="D:/zipfilefolder/#fileName#.zip" type="application/x-zip-compressed" >
```

Comment: I would have made the zip file name more random in the event of simulataneous requests.

Comment: *in the event of simulataneous requests* The download may fail or get corrupted when multiple threads try to update the same file at the same time. Using unique file names avoids that issue. You may also want to use deletefile to automatically remove the temp files.

Comment: Updated the code according to Leigh's and Dan's comment.

Comment: (Edit) Never mind I misread your example. You are already doing what I described ;) Good job!